# Modify the file parameters in plupload

Tags: plupload

I am using plupload. I cannot find a way to edit the name that the upload script sets for the file I am uploading.

Is there a way to change the file name?

Comment: Looks like it's missing from the doc. Asking of SO is good, fixing the problem is better, no? https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/666

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the name for upload field using **file_data_name** option. By default is set to **file**.